# Zermelo–Fraenkel and relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory '$\in$' is a fundamental dyadic relation. On the other side, in ZF a dyadic relation is a set of ordered pairs. So I wonder: does in ZF exists the following set $\{\langle x,y \rangle| x \in y \}$? That is, is it legitimate to build such a set?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that would be a proper class. If $S$ is a set, then $S \in P(S)$, so $\langle S, P(S)\rangle$ would be in that set.

Comment: Use \langle and \rangle for delimiters, not < and > (which are relation symbols, and get different spacing).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $\{\langle x,y\rangle | x\in y\}$ is a valid set in ZF, equal to $y\times\{ y \}$.

Comment: It is unclear if $x$ and $y$ are both unbound variables, or if they are bound. I believe the OP is trying to create a set that codifies the relation $\in$ over all sets, and that would not be a set.